# Can I use XAMPP for real serving?

Tags: security, xampp

Can I use XAMPP for real to serve to WWW, not just my localhost? I see some warnings in some articles on internet not to do that and that XAMPP is for testing only and that hackers will screw it up... If so, what kind of SPECIFIC security holes and problems does it have that is not secure to serve for real?

I don't want some lose answers. I want SPECIFIC answer about the security holes or weaknesses of XAMPP. Thanks!

Comment: Ignoring XAMPP in particular you should never serve a real website from your local computer. All it needs is one programming flaw and a malicious user will be able to access your files. Also it will be against the terms and conditions of many ISP's so be careful

Comment: @Braders, I forgot completely about the usage terms of your service provider. Mine is perfectly ok as long as the usage is low. I use mine for myself and the family so no great network traffic. I also run it on a standalone pc that does nothing else but run the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, more a long comment.

Here be Dragons:

The issue with the 'out of the box' XAMPP setup is that all the passwords are defaults and everyone knows them. **You need to change every password**. If you are not using certain  services then disable them if you don't want to bother changing the password.I disabled DAV for this reason. I use XAMPP as an internet facing server and never have bother. I am on version 1.7.7. been using it for years.

If you are using it on a 'home' network with dynamic ip. If you want a domain name then you need to use a service that provides support for your ip address changing regularly. i use 'dyn' but there are others.

As @Braders has commented. **Security is a major issue!** Get it wrong and your server will be used for all sorts of nasties, both to your pc and others on the internet. I would suggest an **external scan for security issues before you leave it permanently connected to the internet**.

I set my server up a few years ago and i am starting to remember all the checks i made at the time. It took many days before i could 'trust' it. Lots of time looking at the access logs etc.

If you are not sure then do not do it. It is very easy to get the setup wrong.

The major issue with running any server is that you are making 'holes' in the firewall and that can be 'interesting' as to what comes in.

As was also mentioned by Braders, you really do need to check with your internet provider to ensure it is allowed by your agreement.